# How to implement a unified interface of child classes's iterators in base class?

Tags: c++, iterator, polymorphism

In C++, say I have a base class `Base`, and many child classes are derived from it. Each child class contains an array of some type and length.

```
class Base {
    //...
    int baseData;
    virtual ChildIterator getBegin();
    virtual ChildIterator getEnd();
};
class Child1 : public Base {
    // ...
    static const size_t CAPACITY = 5;
    int ints[CAPACITY];
    ChildIterator getBegin() { return &ints[0]; }
    ChildIterator getEnd() { return &ints[CAPACITY]; };
};
class Child2 : public Base {
    // ...
    static const size_t CAPACITY = 7;
    float floats[CAPACITY];
    ChildIterator getBegin() { return &floats[0]; }
    ChildIterator getEnd() { return &floats[CAPACITY]; };
};
```

Now, I want to make each child class iterable, meaning, I can iterate through each child object's array member, as in:

```
Base *p1 = new Child1(...);
Base *p2 = new Child2(...);

sort(p1->getBegin(), p1->getEnd());
// same as: sort(&((Child1)p1->ints[0]), &((Child1)p1->ints[5]));

sort(p2->getBegin(), p2->getBegin() + 3);
// same as: sort(&((Child2)p2->floats[0]), &((Child2)p2->floats[3]));



// Please note that sort() is not my intended operation on them;
// I just use it as an example because it involves iterators. I know
// I could just define sort() method in each child class.
```

How should I implement `ChildIterator` class so that it is a valid random access iterator?

**EDIT**:

The types in the array are not just `int` or `float`; it could be `Base *` or `Child *`, and I need to access `Base`'s members through `ChildIterator` if the type in the array is `Base *`.

Comment: @Jarod42 No - types can be any, even `Base *`

Comment: Then it is impossible (in general). What type should `*ChildIterator{}` be?

Comment: @PasserBy: a proxy type having some kind of `std::any` ?

Comment: I was hoping there exists some clever trick to work around..

Comment: @Jarod42 You would need to build some vtable at compile time for the various operations on that proxy. That is impossible unless you restrict the operations to a fixed set.

Comment: either proxy type for content or CRTP - curiously recursive template pattern, but both aren't quite this

Comment: @Swift It's recurring not recursive ;)

Comment: @BartoszKP i stand corrected.. technically that synonyms, but english term is set on recurring. my language've got only single word for that

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use template class for that. Look at my example for class with array of integers with size 5.

```
class Base
{
   // Dummy
};

template<typename TArray, int size>
class Container : public Base
{
public:
    TArray* getBegin()
    {
       return elements;
    }

    TArray* getEnd()
    {
       return elements + size;
    }

private:
    TArray elements[size];
};

class Child : public Container<int, 5>
{
    // Some Child class specific implementation
};
```

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work if I want the element type to be `Base *`.

Comment: umm.. I have to admit this is pretty clever! Let me think for a day or two to see if it can handle some other corner cases :)

Comment: I just see that probably this won't fit your need, as there is no access to iterator from Base* and some casting will be needed.

Comment: oh did you mean I need to access Base * from iterator? Indeed you're right. Let me add this to the question.

Comment: I'm afraid that you won't be able to satisfy all requirements in this problem. Please see this question with answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240799/generic-base-class-with-multiple-template-specialized-derived-classes